# How can I make my website more responsive to mobile?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have created my online portfolio and it works fine on desktop. However, whenever I try it on other devices/smartphones, it's no longer responsive. I have the meta tags on my code and I have also a media query on my css. I'm coding it using bootstrap and external css. Also, another problem I am having is the horizontal scroll on mobile.

PS. Removed some vital info on texts.

Here is the code that I'm having a problem with.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-center p-3">PROJECTS</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7 text-center">
            <h5 class="educare">Title</h5>
            <p class="text-justify py-1">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
            <p class="text-center py-1 tech-stack">
                Tech Stack:
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/doodle/48/000000/squarespace.png"/>
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/000000/html.png"/>
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/000000/css.png"/>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 text-left order-md-last order-sm-first">
            <img src="..." class="educ-image">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <img src="./images/venture.gif" class="mr-auto venture-gif">
        <div class="col-md-7 text-center">
            <h5 class="venture-txt">Venture Capital Funds Website</h5>
            <p class="text-justify py-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
            <p class="text-center py-1 tech-stack">
                Tech Stack:
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/wix.png"/>
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/000000/adobe-photoshop--v1.png"/>
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/000000/adobe-illustrator.png"/>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It looks fine in the browser responsive view all the way down to 320px wide (iPhone 5).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your mobile scroll should be caused by (elements taking more than device width)..

-Check Elements width in the mobile version & make sure they're taking 100% width in certain media queries..

Comment: The max width on my media query is 768px. Should I change it to a bigger or smaller one?